# YouCompleteMe GoToDefinition for java gives 'RuntimeError: Cannot jump to location' when used on classes from Maven Dependencies

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me

I've been using ycm for Python and Go, trying to configure ycm to work with Java.

I've installed `java 8`, `maven`, recompiled ycm with `--java-completer` and done `mvn install` in a repo that contains a `pom.xml`

Example

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
```

running `YcmCompleter GetDoc` on `Autowired` returns the full documentation of Autowired.

However running `GoTo`, `GoToDeclaration`..etc commands return:
`RuntimeError: Cannot jump to location`

Is this behaviour expected or is there something that I'm missing, such as a configuration in `.ycm_extra_conf.py` to include such that the definitions of dependencies can be found by ycm? i understand java-semantic completion is still under experimental mode, any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Your question looks interesting, though I’m wondering if maybe it’s hard to jump to declarations in downloaded jars? You might want to ask on YCM’s Github about this

Comment: Hi there, thanks! Yeah, I'll share an update if I find any workarounds